# Where's the rxvt-native utility gone in cygwin 1.7.26 for 64bit windows?

Tags: cygwin, windows-7-x64, rxvt

I've always used rxvt-native program on cygwin. I installed the 64 bit cygwin and I cannot find an rxvt package in there. I installed the 32 bit cygwin of the same version and it seems it's still there.

Anyone have any ideas why this package would not be available for 64bit installations of cygwin? and any way to get it?

Comment: Did you get anything on this?

Comment: Nope. Joined the cygwin mailing list but got no reply on it. I'm just using the 32b at the moment.

Comment: AFAICT Larry Hall wanted to port it (http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2013-09/msg00032.html) but apparently never got round to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many 32-bit packages have not yet been ported to 64-bit, for various reasons. The most common is that the maintainer just hasn't had time, or may not have access to a 64-bit Cygwin environment. Often a new maintainer is needed.

You can find the complete list [here](http://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-64bit-missing). Yes, rxvt is on it.

Comment: Thanks... ah well. I'll be sticking to 32 for now.