# How can I compile a hybrid (asm, C) source code into a 32bit program?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, cygwin, nasm

I am using Cygwin under Win7 in a 64-bit machine.

The following program compiles in 64-bit mode without any issue.

### makefile

```
runme: main.cpp asm.o
    g++ main.cpp asm.o -o executable

asm.o: asm.asm
    nasm -f elf64 asm.asm -o asm.o
```

### asm.asm

```
section .data
section .bss
section .text
    global GetValueFromASM

GetValueFromASM:
    mov eax, 9
    ret
```

### main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

extern "C" int GetValueFromASM();

int main()
{
    cout<<"GetValueFromASM() returned = "<<GetValueFromASM()<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

But, I want to compile it in 32-bit mode. So, I changed `elf64` to `elf` and my new makefile looks like the following:

### makefile

```
runme: main.cpp asm.o
    g++ main.cpp asm.o -o executable

asm.o: asm.asm
    nasm -f elf asm.asm -o asm.o
```

But, I am getting the following error:

```
$ make
nasm -f elf asm.asm -o asm.o
g++ main.cpp asm.o -o executable
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: i386 
architecture of input file `asm.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:4: runme] Error 1
```

What could be the reason?

How can I get around this issue?

**Edit-1**: I have added `-m32` option in `g++`. Now, the error is as follows:

```
$ make
g++ -m32 main.cpp asm.o -o executable
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0//libstdc++.dll.a when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0//libstdc++.a when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0//libstdc++.a when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/libstdc++.dll.a when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/libstdc++.a when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/libstdc++.a when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0//libstdc++.dll.a when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0//libstdc++.a when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/libstdc++.dll.a when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/libstdc++.a when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0//libgcc_s.dll.a when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/libgcc_s.dll.a when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0//libgcc_s.dll.a when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/libgcc_s.dll.a when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0//libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0//libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0//libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/../../../libcygwin.a when searching for -lcygwin
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/../../../libcygwin.a when searching for -lcygwin
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/../../../libcygwin.a when searching for -lcygwin
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lcygwin
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -ladvapi32
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lshell32
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -luser32
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lkernel32
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0//libgcc_s.dll.a when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/libgcc_s.dll.a when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0//libgcc_s.dll.a when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/libgcc_s.dll.a when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0//libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0//libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0//libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:4: runme] Error 1
```

Comment: You need to tell g++ as well that you want 32 bit output. Add `-m32` option.

Comment: @Jester, adding `-m32` is giving even bigger error.

Comment: 64-bit MINGW does not support generating 32-bit executable files that simply. A lot of library files are missing...

Comment: You will need to install the 32 bit cygwin stuff.

Comment: If you want to get the libraries the easy way, here is my suggestion: 
Remove cygwin and Install msys2 from msys2.org
run in msys2 shell: "pacman -S base-devel mingw-w64-i686-toolchain mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain  mingw-w64-x86_64-nasm"
Add the following to path: "C:\msys64\usr\bin" and depending on which you want default "C:\msys64\mingw64\bin"  or "C:\msys64\mingw32\bin"
Also it is easy to update, just run "pacman -Syu" from time to time.

Comment: @nulleight, hmmm....good info. Let me try.

Comment: You can search packages and libs to install with "pacman -Ss <libname>"
You can also install nano editor or mc (midnight commander) if you are a linux user and have to use windows.
Also when you install make, you have to call it with "mingw32-make" instead of just make. There are also alot of libraries and tools like python with both 64 and 32 bit installable side by side.

Comment: Where did you get *nasm*? What about installing *32bit* *Cygwin* as well? Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54206577/can-you-run-a-32-bit-cygwin-application-in-a-64-bit-installation/54216105#54216105.

Comment: @CristiFati, In Cygwin64.

Comment: Sure, I've also checked *setup.exe* (should have done it before posting the comment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I pointed it out in the comment, [[SO]: Can you run a 32 bit Cygwin application in a 64 bit installation? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54206577/can-you-run-a-32-bit-cygwin-application-in-a-64-bit-installation/54216105#54216105) contains lots of useful info.

I want to start with 2 observations:

- *gcc* *64bit* needs the *-m32* flag (and viceversa: *gcc* *32bit* needs *-m64*), otherwise they will generate binaries that match their *CPU* architecture. *32bit* and *64bit* object (*.o*) files are incompatible (when passed to the linker) and it will fail
- *Cygwin* (including *gcc*) **uses *Win* executables format or *PE*** ([[Wikipedia]: Portable Executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable)). *nasm*'s output formats (*elf32* and *elf64*) **generate *ELF*s** ([[Wikipedia]: Executable and Linkable Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format)). I don't know how this works (well obviously, somewhere a format conversion takes place, but I don't know where exactly). For rigorousity's sake, I'll be using their *Win* counterparts (*win32* and *win64*) which work as well (check `nasm -hf`)

I too encountered the same behavior on *Cygwin 32* (before you edited the question):

```bash
[cfati@cfati-5510-0:/cygdrive/e/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q055497459]> ~/sopr.sh
*** Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ***

[prompt]> uname -a
CYGWIN_NT-10.0-WOW cfati-5510-0 2.11.2(0.329/5/3) 2018-11-08 14:30 i686 Cygwin
[prompt]>
[prompt]> ls
asm.asm  asm.o  builds  main.cpp  Makefile
[prompt]> make
MAKE Version 5.2  Copyright (c) 1987, 1998 Inprise Corp.
        g++  -o main.o -c  main.cpp
        g++   -o executable main.o asm.o -lstdc++
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x5a): undefined reference to `GetValueFromASM'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

** error 1 ** deleting executable
```

I must mention that I don't have *nasm* installed here, so I've built (the *32bit*) *asm.o* on *Cygwin 64*. Since switching between terminals is annoying, I completely switched to *Cygwin 64*, where I have the *32bit* *gcc* (*i686-pc-cygwin-gcc*) installed.

I've also modified 2 of your files (*Makefile* can be improved a lot, but that's not the main focus now).

*main.cpp*:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

extern "C" int GetValueFromASM();


int main() {
    cout << "sizeof(void*): " << sizeof(void*) << endl;
    cout << "GetValueFromASM() returned: " << GetValueFromASM() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

*Makefile*:

```bash
.PHONY: all clean executable

objects = main.o asm.o
cpp = g++
cpp = i686-pc-cygwin-gcc
#m32_flag = -m32
asm_out_format = win32
#link_verbose_flag = -v

all: executable

clean:
    rm -f $(objects) executable

executable: $(objects)
    $(cpp) $(link_verbose_flag) $(m32_flag) -o $@ $(objects) -lstdc++

asm.o: asm.asm
    nasm -f $(asm_out_format) -o $@ $?

main.o: main.cpp
    $(cpp) $(m32_flag) -o $@ -c $?
```

After a few attempts, I identified the cause of the problem:

```bash
[cfati@cfati-5510-0:/cygdrive/e/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q055497459]> ~/sopr.sh
*** Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ***

[prompt]> uname -a
CYGWIN_NT-10.0 cfati-5510-0 3.0.5(0.338/5/3) 2019-03-31 11:17 x86_64 Cygwin
[prompt]>
[prompt]> ls
asm.asm  builds  main.cpp  Makefile
[prompt]> make
i686-pc-cygwin-gcc  -o main.o -c main.cpp
nasm -f win32 -o asm.o asm.asm
i686-pc-cygwin-gcc   -o executable main.o asm.o -lstdc++
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x5a): undefined reference to `GetValueFromASM'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:17: executable] Error 1
[prompt]>
[prompt]> nm -S asm.o | grep GetValueFromASM
00000000 T GetValueFromASM
[prompt]>
[prompt]> nm -S main.o | grep GetValueFromASM
         U _GetValueFromASM
```

So (notice the *GetValueFromASM* *vs.* ***_***GetValueFromASM mismatch), it's a matter of *name mangling* (although the error message is not very helpful) that happens on *Win* (***32bit* only**). 
[[SO]: Adding leading underscores to assembly symbols with GCC on Win32? (@ephemient's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034852/adding-leading-underscores-to-assembly-symbols-with-gcc-on-win32/1035937#1035937) did the trick (there are other solutions, but they don't look very nice). All you need to do is **changing *GetValueFromASM*'s declaration to**:

```c
extern "C" int GetValueFromASM() asm ("GetValueFromASM");
```

and after building (on *Cygwin 64*):

> ```bash
> [prompt]> uname -a
> CYGWIN_NT-10.0-WOW cfati-5510-0 2.11.2(0.329/5/3) 2018-11-08 14:30 i686 Cygwin
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> file executable.exe
> executable.exe: PE32 executable (console) Intel 80386, for MS Windows
> [prompt]> ./executable.exe
> sizeof(void*): 4
> GetValueFromASM() returned: 9
> ```